# Change ons-list look and feel to CardView

Tags: onsen-ui, android-cardview

Is there any way to change `onsen-ui` lists (`ons-list`) to look like a `CardView` as the below picture.

[image]

The borders are set in background and I tried to change them and setting padding and margin with no chance.

Comment: There is not built-in component like this in Onsen UI so you would have to write it yourself or find it in some other library.

Comment: Is there any way to change the css to become like this? Or since it is becomming so popular do you have any plan to provide it as a modifier in future?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By changing these styles I have achieved the below picture

```
.list__item{
    border-style:solid !important;
    border-width:1px !important;
    border-color:#ddd !important;
    box-shadow:2px 2px 1px #eee !important;
    margin:10px !important;
}
```

[image]